# Adding a Div response on ActionPerformed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this javascript/ajax code that I have been tweaking for half a day now to just add a div response that was echoed by php script. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select id="machine" name="machine" class="field" >
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose..</option>
<option value="machine1.php">Machine 1</option>
<option value="machine2.php">Machine 2</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend><strong>Select a file to upload</strong></legend>

    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" size="40" multiple="multiple" />
     <br />
      <p></p>
       <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="upload" />
       <br />
        <br />
    </form>
    <div id="information"></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>Uploaded Files</strong></legend>
    <div id="uploaded"></div>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addaction(actionvalue){
$("#form1").attr("action",actionvalue);
};
</script>
```

Comment: where is ajax call???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GHOST93 said, there's no AJAX call in your code.
But to me it seems like you're trying to change the action attribute based on what is selected in the select box. That by itself doesn't need an Ajax call.

Try adding something like this into your script
http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7431/

```
$("#machine").change(function(){
    $("#form1").attr("action", $(this).val());
});
```

And you can probably drop your addaction() function.

Comment: I will workaround with the code that you provide and I will check if it will turn out right.